Send alert/Logic apps if Azure ML pipeline Completed with Azure ML Pipeline Outputs attached to email
I am trying to add an alert/logic apps if Azure ML pipeline completed with Azure ML Output attached in email.
It looks that one of the ways is to create a monitor in the Azure Portal and other way is to create Logic apps.
If i use Azure Monitor - Alerts , is there any eventtype like 'JobCompleted' ?
AmlComputeJobEvent
| where ExperimentName == 'mslearn-train-diabetes'
| where EventType == 'JobCompleted'
Can you please suggest ?


To get the status you can use below design:

Then:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/<workspacename>/jobs/<runidorjobid>?api-version=2024-04-01


Given Below roles for Logic app Manged Identity:
AzureML Compute Operator
AzureML Metrics Writer
Monitoring Contributor
then:

In Parse_Json:
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "properties": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "tags": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {}
                },
                "properties": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "azureml.runsource": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "runSource": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "runType": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "azureml.parameters": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "azureml.continue_on_step_failure": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "azureml.continue_on_failed_optional_input": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "azureml.defaultComputeName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "azureml.defaultDataStoreName": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "azureml.pipelineComponent": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "azureml.pipelines.stages": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "displayName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "status": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "experimentName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "services": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "Tracking": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "jobServiceType": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "port": {},
                                "endpoint": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "status": {},
                                "errorMessage": {},
                                "properties": {},
                                "nodes": {}
                            }
                        },
                        "Studio": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "jobServiceType": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "port": {},
                                "endpoint": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "status": {},
                                "errorMessage": {},
                                "properties": {},
                                "nodes": {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "computeId": {},
                "isArchived": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "identity": {},
                "componentId": {},
                "notificationSetting": {},
                "jobType": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "settings": {},
                "jobs": {},
                "inputs": {},
                "outputs": {},
                "sourceJobId": {}
            }
        },
        "systemData": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "createdAt": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "createdBy": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "createdByType": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:


If you only want mail when status is completed, use condition action and in that check the body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['status'] is equal to Completed, In true use Outlook action.
Alternatively, you can use below Trigger and followed Document:

then parse the json output of trigger and then send it as mail.
